# The implementions of RWMutex.Lock() in golang

Tags: go, locking

in [src/sync/rwmutex.go](https://golang.org/src/sync/rwmutex.go) file, we can see the definition of "Lock" as follows:

```
func (rw *RWMutex) Lock() {
    if race.Enabled {
        _ = rw.w.state
        race.Disable()
    }
    // First, resolve competition with other writers.
    rw.w.Lock()
    // Announce to readers there is a pending writer.
    r := atomic.AddInt32(&rw.readerCount, -rwmutexMaxReaders) + rwmutexMaxReaders
    // Wait for active readers.
    if r != 0 && atomic.AddInt32(&rw.readerWait, r) != 0 {
        runtime_Semacquire(&rw.writerSem)
    }
    if race.Enabled {
        race.Enable()
        race.Acquire(unsafe.Pointer(&rw.readerSem))
        race.Acquire(unsafe.Pointer(&rw.writerSem))
    }
}
```

So I really wonder what

```
atomic.AddInt32(&rw.readerCount, -rwmutexMaxReaders) + rwmutexMaxReaders
```

this sentence means. And as it says, how to **announce to readers**? How to understand it?

Comment: rw.readerCount <= rwmutexMaxReaders, so rw.readerCount-rwmutexMaxReaders makes readerCount 0 or negativ (the signal). Adding back rwmutxMaxReaders makes r equal the real number of readerWait.

Answer (score 3):

On a RWMutex a writer calling Lock prevents more readers from acquiring the RLock. This is done to prevent [starvation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)) of writers.

Suppose the following scenario:

1. Suppose a reader has acquired the read lock, then `rw.readerCount` will be 1.
2. A writer then tries to acquire the write lock. After acquiring the write lock ([line 93](https://golang.org/src/sync/rwmutex.go#L93)) it now has to signal all the readers that a writer is waiting (so they can't continue) and wait for all the readers to finish. The signal is set by setting `rw.readerCount` to a negative value (`atomic.AddInt32(&rw.readerCount, -rwmutexMaxReaders)`). The value of `rw.readerCount` is now `1-rwmutexMaxReaders`. Note that `r` is not 0, so the writer knows there is a reader still reading.
3. A new Reader now wants to acquire the read lock, it adds 1 to `rw.readerCount` (line 48) and checks if it is negative. If it is negative a writer has set it as such, and we should wait for the writer to finish before continuing.

The signaling happens around the sign of `rw.readerCount`.

Comment: Great answer. Unfortunately, the code references are not applicable anymore as the original code has changed. Would be great if the code is pasted as part of the answer, and references (line numbers) are updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Do you like magic? This is that ;o) No .. I'm just kidding.

We could start with

```
atomic.AddInt32(&rw.readerCount, -rwmutexMaxReaders)
```

This atomically substract rwmutexMaxReaders from rw.readerCount. New value is stored into rw.readerCount and also returned by function. And when you will add rwmutexMaxReaders you just compute old value rw.readerCount before AddInt32.